# What's wrong with this syntax of extending two classes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to extend two classes, but I every variation of syntax that I can think of yields an error. I can't find a single example online of two classes being extended. Is it possible? How do I do what I tried below, the correct way?

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity, FacebookSDK {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend two classes at the same time with Dart. Also you don't have public and private keywords in Dart.

You can either extend from a `Class` that extends from another, or use `Mixins`, which are a way to implement new functionality to classes.

> To implement a mixin, create a class that extends Object and declares
> no constructors. Unless you want your mixin to be usable as a regular
> class, use the mixin keyword instead of class.

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and
> private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private
> to its library.

```
class Car extends Vehicle with Radio {
  Car(String model) {
    model = model;
    canDrive = true;
  }
}

mixin Radio {
  void playSong() {
      print('playing a song');
  }
}
```